# Append to array through Axios & React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I would like to append an object to an array of JSON through axios and react.
I have tried with a put request by doing so this, but it just overrides the whole array so only the new data is there.

```
axios.put(url, {
            KPIS: [
              values.form
            ]
          } )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data); 
  
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly dependent upon the how the API is programmed to handle put. Typically it will just replace the value with whatever you send.

However, you can always append the data to the array yourself and then call put on it. You could do something like this to add the form value to your current array. You will have to get that current value first by using a get request or however the API works.

```
axios.put(url, {
            KPIS: [
              ...currentArray, values.form
            ]
          } )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data); 
  
      })
```